# Can I use {% static %} outside the base.html in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I am a beginner in Django and i have setup a project with a base.html file along with the folder static/images/img.jpg.

base.html is setup correctly. Everything works inside this file but i have another file called index.html in the templates folder.

So, in other words in the base.html i can use the command {% static '/images/img. jpg' %} but in my index.html Django does not recognise the command.

In the index.html I have already provided the required commands {% extends 'base.html' %} and {% load static %}

Does this command work only in the base html? Do i need another command for files outside the base.html

Thank You

Comment: Can you share the `index.hmtl` file that does not work?

Comment: you have to have {% load static %} prior to it https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files

Answer (score 0):

This command should work on every template file of Django, take a look if you are putting the code between a block `{% block %} {% endblock %}` or even if your IDE don't autocorrect it, run it and see if it works correctly

Comment: found the problem . I used (%load static% ) in my template html  insead of curly braces. Thank you for your answers